# How get collection of entities from eav_entity by custom type?

Tags: collection, custom-options, eav, resource-model, entities

I created custom eav type:

```
/* @var $installer Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup */
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addEntityType('av_photo_type', array(
    'entity_model' => 'av_photo/eav_photo'
));

$installer->addAttribute('av_photo_type', 'name', array(
    'label'        => 'Type Name'
));

$installer->addAttribute('av_photo_type', 'code', array(
    'label'         => 'Unique Code',
    'unique'        => 1,
    'note'          => 'For internal using'
));

$installer->addAttribute('av_photo_type', 'order', array(
    'label'         => 'Order'
));

$installer->addAttribute('av_photo_type', 'active', array(
    'label'         => 'Active',
    'type'          => 'int',
    'input'          => 'boolean',
));
```

I've created file /model/eav/Photo.php:

```
class Company_Photo_Model_Eav_Photo extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
        $this->setType('av_photo_type')->setConnection(
            $resource->getConnection('sales_read'),
            $resource->getConnection('sales_write')
        );
    }
}
```

I would like to get collection by type "av_photo_type" now. I should create resource file to get collection but I haven't custom tables. Magento eav module hasn't resource model for eav_entity table. How to get eav_entity collection then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-7-advanced-orm-entity-attribute-value

```
$installer->createEntityTables(
    $this->getTable('complexworld/eavblogpost')
);
```

The article is really long...

If the tables exist, you can use a collection extended from EAV collection

```
class Magentotutorial_Complexworld_Model_Resource_Eavblogpost_Collection extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('complexworld/eavblogpost');
    }
}
```

Comment: I mean how to do that using only mage class without extending course I'm using native functionality.

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: Your way you described is correct, but you create custom class Magentotutorial_Complexworld_Model_Resource_Eavblogpost_Collection. I would like to get collection using only smth like Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection, but there are not such class. I would not create custom classes.

Comment: You have a custom entity, you create a custom class, that's the magento way. Even if the class only defined its main_table and the primary key column.